# Sync with Azure Active Directory with a multi-tenant app (receiving user notifications)

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I've developed a feature on my web-site that allow to log-in using Azure.

So users in my web-site can sign-in using:

- Azure (OAuth2). We're using a multi-tenant app. We're just using the application to log in users. So we don't really use the Access-Token to make requests. We just use the access-token to obtain the user email (decoding it with JWT).
- Their own email-password they can set on my site.

---

This creates a problem:

Imagine an person that starts working in a company. The IT team give him an email that belongs to their azure account (with their account domain). This team also have an account on my site (configured with the same domains they use on Azure). So this user will try to log in my site using his credentials. We'll create his profile on their company account (due to the email domain). He sets his password. Sometimes he use Azure to log-in and sometimes he use his email-password to log-in.

The next month and, this person get fired. The IT team delete him from Azure. Although, the IT team forget about deleting him also on my site. So this user has permissions to sign-in with his email-password credentials and still be able to see private information (he can even delete private files).

---

I would like to know if there is a way to sync my app with every Directory that is using it. So I would be able to receive user action notifications (like user deletions). It would be great to receive a call to an endpoint with information about users important actions. This way we'll be able to delete the user also from our platform. So the company can forget about deleting an user on my site without having the stolen-information problem.

PS: I've seen you have a logout sync using SAML, but I wonder if we would be able to receive other kind of notifications, because we don't want to log-out the user when this logs-out from Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been talking with microsoft support and there is no way of having microsoft calling our endpoint to receive some notifications.

So the only solution is ask for admin permission or, having the refresh_token from Oauth2, check the user still appears on Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me).

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission from the ex-user tenant administrator to access their directory, you can check if the user is listed or not by using [Microsoft Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations)

Comment: That's a good idea. The problem is: when do i have to check if the user belongs to that accout? Let's say I do it every time that he logs in, then I won't delete that user if he is already log-in. So I still need a to receive a notification. Another option is read log-out notifications using SAML but I don't want my users to log-out from my web-site everytime they log-out from azure

Comment: As far as I know, Azure AD doesn't send such notifications that you are looking for. I don't think you need one. When the user provides his credentials on your web site, before you give him authorization, you verify his email address with the external company's directory. If the email account is not there or is marked as inactive, you don't give him access.